# numpy argsort() returning wrong result

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

```
a = np.array(['0.4369217975174501', '9.813778651781852e-05', '0.3682690408090255'])
print(a[a.argsort()])
```

Output:

```
['0.3682690408090255' '0.4369217975174501' '9.813778651781852e-05']
```

while it should be:

```
['9.813778651781852e-05' '0.3682690408090255' '0.4369217975174501']
```

Why is that? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you try to compare string

```
 a = np.array(['0.4369217975174501', '9.813778651781852e-05', '0.3682690408090255'])
 b = np.array(list(map(float, ['0.4369217975174501', '9.813778651781852e-05', '0.3682690408090255'])))
 print(a[a.argsort()])
 print(b[b.argsort()])

    ['0.3682690408090255' '0.4369217975174501' '9.813778651781852e-05']
    [9.81377865e-05 3.68269041e-01 4.36921798e-01]
```

better way from  G. Anderson

```
print(a[a.astype(float).argsort()])
```

Comment: Only note I would say; `a[a.astype(float).argsort()]` can keep the array as string type but sort it numerically, and runs in less time than `array(list(map(float...`

Comment: I'm dumb. Thanks for a quick answer. The original dataset I was having this problem on is indeed all strings, and I didn't even realize it (even though I just so happened to make the same error in the OP by creating an array of strings). Lucky me.